# Ng-repeat Firebase snap.val

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Quick question (I hope):
I am trying to `ng-repeat` through data in my `$scope.discover` I use the following code to fill that scope: 
`

```
const businessKey = '-KQ1hFH0qrvKSrymmn9d';
                const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
                const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
                const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');


                function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
                    discoverRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
                        let businesRef = businessRef.child(snap.key);
                        businesRef.once('value', cb);
                    });
                }

                getDiscoverBarContent(businessKey, snap => {
                    console.log(snap.val());
                    $scope.discover = snap.val();
                });`
And then a simple ng-repeat:
`<a ng-repeat="item in discover" >{{item.name}}</a>`
```

However this is not working and returning a line of code :confused: Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close but needed to create an empty discover array and push the snap results to that scope array. See modified code below:

```
$scope.discover = [];
    const businessKey = $scope.finalItem.$id;
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const discoverRef = rootRef.child('discover');
    const businessRef = rootRef.child('businesses');


    function getDiscoverBarContent(key, cb) {
        discoverRef.child(key).on('child_added', snap => {
            let businesRef = businessRef.child(snap.key);
            businesRef.once('value', cb);
        });
    }

    getDiscoverBarContent(businessKey, snap => {
        var snapVal = snap.val();
        $scope.discover.push(snapVal);
    });
```

This solution is not live updating as that would require more complexity such as Firebase handles etc.